# MVC Routing not working as expected / how to debug

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to debug an error with routing which isn't picking up my two integers

The two questions I have are:

1. Why is the requested link not being matched correctly?
2. how can I debug such issues? I've tried Phil Haacks routedebugger and
   Glimpse however these only work when the requested output doesn't error. I ideally would like to see which route is being matched for this erroring request.

**My Controller looks like:**
[image: Controller Text]

**My Global.asax Route**
[image: The Routing]

**The Error I'm receiving**
The first int is -1 however it still errors when it's a positive number.
[image: The Actual Error]

Comment: What is the error with a positive number? You're aware your regex constraint won't match a negative number yeah?

Comment: Hi Simon - It's the same error. I added the constraint to ensure there were not any other "greedy" routes in my Global.asax. It errors with the same message with positive numbers. The screenshot  with the -1 request was made before I added the constraints. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error locally. Have you tried with UrlParameter.Optional for both taskId and serviceId in your route? Can you show all of your routes?

Comment: Thanks for your help Simon - Adding UrlParameter.Optional works, however I don't understand why that would be the case?

Comment: I'm not sure.. because with only your route and a default route, I didn't require the UrlParameter.Optional. Sounds like another route was interfering.

Comment: You're spot on - It was another route that was too greedy. I looked over my other routes so many times and was 99% sure that wasn't the case but it was. If you submit an answer I'll be sure to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I'm totally rep-hungry, I'm going to put my correct comment here.. :D

UrlParameter.Optional will fix it, however, this is probably due to a conflicting route somewhere, as I did not require that on my tests locally.

Also, for anyone else wondering, for negative numbers in your constraint, you'll need to have a regex like this: `-{0,1}\d+`